# Application crashing when click on any item in ListView

Tags: java, android, listview

I am a beginner in Android studio and I am having hard time to debug this issue.

when any item in my ListView gets clicked the application crashes, here is the class for the OnItemClick. The objective is to change the ListView from the Categories to the items inside the categories. The Categories and items are stored in a `HashMap <String, String[]>`, so passing the value of `cat.toString()` should return the string containing the category. Lastly using `myList` (Stored outside of the function) should return an array of string containing the items. However, when I click any of the items the application instantly crashes. Thanks for your help!

```
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
    //Choosen category
    TextView cat = (TextView) view;
    ArrayList<String> tempItems = new ArrayList<String>();
    //Toast.makeText(this, cat.getText().toString(),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    listAdapter.clear();
    for(String val : myList.get(cat.getText().toString())){
        tempItems.add(val);
    }
    listAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,tempItems);
    listAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```

Variables

```
ListView myViewList;
Map<String, String[]> myList = new HashMap<String, String[]>();
ArrayAdapter<String> listAdapter;
```

Populating the ListView

```
    //Creating a list of all categories
    Set<String> myListKeys = myList.keySet();
    ArrayList<String> categories = new ArrayList<String>();
    for(String val : myListKeys){
        categories.add(val);
    }
    //String[] categories = myListKeys.toArray(new String[myListKeys.size()]);

    //Populating list
    myViewList = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.groceryList);
    listAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,categories);
    myViewList.setAdapter(listAdapter);
    myViewList.setOnItemClickListener(this);
```

Comment: please post the log.

Comment: @JohnJoe ~~Having hard time to figure out how to retrieve it, mind helping out? Thanks!!~~ Added

Comment: what is line `MainActivity.java:48` ?

Comment: @JohnJoe listAdapter.clear();

Comment: can you remove it and see how things go?

Comment: @JohnJoe Removed, but when I click anything on the ListView nothing happens

Comment: What did you mean by _"The objective is to change the ListView from the Categories to the items inside the categories."_

Comment: @JohnJoe I want to remove everything from the list and input (To the ListView) all the items from the category clicked

Comment: Remove all the list adapter first and use `Toast` to check . Did `cat.toString()` print out anythings?

Comment: @JohnJoe EDIT: I have used Toast using cat.getText().toString() and it shows the proper category

Comment: what happened when you use `cat.getText().toString()`

Comment: @JohnJoe It prints out the Category name

Comment: What I meant is replace the `cat.getText().toString()` to your code.

Comment: @JohnJoe I did, still same issue

Comment: What is the error now ? Nothing happened or still crashed ?

Comment: @JohnJoe I have changed the `String[] categories` to an ArrayList and that made it not crash but the ListView doesn't change, then I tried changing the way we add the new items in the OnItemClick, and still nothing changed... BUT NO CRASHES :)

Comment: perhaps you miss  `myViewList.setAdapter(listAdapter);` after line `listAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,tempItems);`

Comment: @JohnJoe That seems to fix it, I apologize for the questions but I learned a lot. Thanks!!

Comment: No problem.....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are getting exception because you are using `listAdapter.clear();` which tries to clear the List inside the adapter. But apparently you have passed an array (`String[] categories`) which cannot be cleared. You should convert the array to **`ArrayList`**, (not just `List`) by iterating through it and pass it into the adapter.

You should create the adapter by passing `ArrayList`

What do you think you're doing by creating a new adapter inside the onItemClick of old adapter?

Inside the onItemClick, don't create a new adapter. Instead, after clearing the adapter and creating a temp ArrayList, add all the temp ArrayList to the adapter.

```
listAdapter.addAll(tempItems);
```

Also to get text from a TextView, use `cat.getText().toString();` instead of `cat.toString();`

Comment: I am trying to update the adapter values, from categories string array to items string array

Comment: I have added the code of how I populate the ListView, that might help expand what you were saying

Comment: I have updated the `String[] categories` and changed it, and it didn't crash but nothing change. So I changed the OnItemClick to do the same, and still nothing changed...

Comment: Sorry to bother you, but mind letting me know why it works with ArrayList but not a regular array? Thanks!!

Comment: Yea thanks, it seems like adding `myViewList.setAdapter(listAdapter);` fixed it, I appreciate you help!!

Comment: Because the data structure of regular array do not let you remove an element from it. But you can remove element from any index in an ArrayList